# strdup() causing memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, strdup

I've implemented a function that returns a string. It takes an integer as a parameter (`age`), and returns a formatted string.

All is working well, except from the fact that I have some crazy memory leaks. I know strdup() is the cause of this, but I've tried to research some fixes to no avail.

My code is:

```
const char * returnName(int age) {

    char string[30];

    sprintf( string, "You are %d years old", age);

    return strdup(string);
}
```

Valgrind's output is:

```
==15414== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15414==    definitely lost: 6,192 bytes in 516 blocks
==15414==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15414==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15414==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15414==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Any help in resolving this memory leak issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've shown the code that allocates, where's the code that frees?

Comment: Did you read any documentation for `strdup`?

Comment: Does code eventually `free()` the pointer returned by `returnName()`?  If not, there is the leak.

Comment: You need to `free` the result of `strdup` at some point, that in turn means you need to change the return-type to just (non-`const`) `char *`.

Comment: How do I free a local variable outside of a function that the variable is local to? To answer the question - I have not freed strdup because of said concern.

Comment: @user2832891 You return a pointer to the allocated memory area, which you can pass to `free`.

Comment: @user2832891 What local variable? You have returned the result of `strdup` to the caller so the caller of the function should `free` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man strdup`:

> Memory for the new string is obtained with
>          `malloc(3)`, and can be freed with `free(3)`.

So you need to `free` the space allocated and returned by `strdup`.

Say you invoke `returnName` like that:

```
 const char* str = returnName(3);
```

After you're done with `str` you can `free` it like this:

```
free((char*) str);
```

The cast is needed because `free` expects a **non-const** `void*`. This explicit conversion is alright here because `returnName` actually should return constant data<sup>1</sup>. Calling `free` is only a nasty implementation detail here.

---

<sup>1</sup> As discussed with @M.M in the comments to this answer.

Comment: What if I am printing in a main method as such: `printf("%s", returnName(3));` so there is no variable name such as `str` assosciated when invoking the method - how would I free it?

Comment: `const char* str = returnName(3); printf("%s\n", str);`

Comment: Was hoping I could avoid explicitly declaring a new variable but I guess that'll have to do. Thanks.

Comment: Getting the following error when trying exactly what you typed: `note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;`

Comment: @user2832891 `const` pointers can't be `free`d apparently. So you need to return `char*` from your function instead.

Comment: The function can still return `const char *`.  Const pointers can be freed. You probably meant that pointers to const can't be freed, however you can cast the pointer to `void *` (or `char *`) before calling `free`.

Comment: @M.M I agree but how can the function return `const char*` then? Conversion from `const T*` to `T*` isn't implicit AFAIK and I (and probably most other C programmers) don't like explicit conversions.

Comment: Many also don't like using non-const pointers to data that is not supposed to be modified :)

Comment: @M.M But memory returned by `strdup` can be modified, right? Otherwise you got a point.

Comment: It can, but OP has intentionally designed his function so that the caller should not modify the returned string.

Comment: @M.M Yes, seems logical. Then this case, casting `const char*` to `char*` is alright. Will add that!

Answer (score 5):

strdup() is essentially equivalent to

```
char* dup = malloc(strlen(original) + 1);
strcpy(dup, original);
```

So you need to remember to call `free()` after you're finished using the string.

```
const char* name = returnName(20);
/* do stuff with name */
free((void*)name);
```

If you don't call `free()`, then of course valgrind reports a leak.

Comment: Asked this below to another user aswell: What if I am printing in a main method as such: `printf("%s", returnName(3));` so there is no variable name such as `name` assosciated when invoking the method - how would I free it? Thanks.

Comment: @user2832891 Then, you've caused a memory leak. You need to associate a variable with it so that you can `free` it later.

Comment: @PCLuddite Did you just made a copy of my Answer ?

Comment: @Michi I didn't try to, but I can see how you might think that. I changed my example to an earlier edit so that there's some variety.

Comment: @Michi And in the spirit of fair play, I upvoted your answer. I apologize for any infringement.

Comment: how can you keep a `const char*` value to a `char*` variable? return type of `returnName(3)` is `const char*`

Answer (score 3):

**strdup** looks something like this:

```
char *strdup(const char *str){
    size_t n = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *dup = malloc(n);

    if(dup){
        strcpy(dup, str);
    }

    return dup;
}
```

As you can see there is `malloc` involved too, which means that at some point after you dynamically allocate that memory using `strdup` you have to `free` it after you don't need it any more.

Answer (score 1):

the cause of the memory leaks is NOT from the call to strdup() but rather because the caller of the posted function is failing to pass the returned pointer to free() when done with the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char * returnName(int age) {
    char string[30];
    sprintf( string, "You are %d years old", age);
    return strdup(string);
}
```

return type of `returnName()` is `const char*`. So, you can not hold the returned value to a `char*` type variable. Hold returned value to a `const char*` variable and `cast` it to `char*` while make memory `free`

```
const char* retName = returnName(3);
// Use retName
free((char*)retName);
```