# Uninitialized value from valgrind

Tags: c, memory, struct, valgrind

```
==2630== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2630==    at 0x4E82D71: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.21.so)
==2630==    by 0x4E88E78: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.21.so)
==2630==    by 0x400C0C: searchWord (T9.c:91)
==2630==    by 0x400A0A: main (T9.c:40) 

==2114==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2114==    at 0x4C28C50: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2114==    by 0x400FD1: newStr (trie_node.c:125)
==2114==    by 0x400F8C: create_trie (trie_node.c:117)
==2114==    by 0x4009D5: main (T9.c:37)
```

I have error message above by running trace function in valgrind. I am pretty sure that I have initialized the variable. 
Here is the struct code:

```
struct wordList* newStr(char* text) {
    char* word;
    struct wordList* tmp = (struct wordList*)malloc(sizeof(struct wordList));
    word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(text) + 1);
    strncpy(word, text, strlen(text));
    tmp->str = word;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}
```

And the code around T9.c line 91:

```
struct wordList* cur;
if (cur && invalid == 0 && flag == 0) {
  printf("\t\'%s\'\n", cur->str);
 }
```

Updates:

I modify the strncpy line from

```
    strncpy(word, text, strlen(text));
```

to

```
word = strncpy(word, text, strlen(text));
```

This solved the uninitialized problem, however I got new error message that I dont understand:

```
==3245== Invalid read of size 1
==3245==    at 0x4E82D71: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.21.so)
==3245==    by 0x4E88E78: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.21.so)
==3245==    by 0x400C0C: searchWord (T9.c:91)
==3245==    by 0x400A0A: main (T9.c:40)
==3245==  Address 0x51f7d45 is 0 bytes after a block of size 5 alloc'd
==3245==    at 0x4C28C50: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3245==    by 0x400FC1: newStr (trie_node.c:124)
==3245==    by 0x400F80: create_trie (trie_node.c:117)
==3245==    by 0x4009D5: main (T9.c:37)
```

Comment: What is the value of `text` though?

Comment: You can leave out `sizeof(char)`, since that'll be 1, but if you want to be explicit, put parentheses around `strlen(text) + 1`. Also, don't cast the return value of malloc: `void *` will find its way to your `char *word` by itself.

Comment: Please post the code in the image and remove the image.

Comment: There's a safer variant of `strncpy` : it's called `strcpy`. Using it here would have avoided this bug.

Comment: @M.M u just solved my problem

Comment: @Big_tboy well, the other two posted answers already pointed it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to see more code, but while I'm not sure this is exactly what valgrind is complaining about, your code does have a major bug in it:

```
strncpy(word, text, strlen(text));
```

You're not null-terminating your string, you're just copying the actual characters. It's particularly funny because there's a function that already takes care of allocating the correct amount of memory and copying strings: [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup).

Also obligatory warning to stop casting the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Null terminate your string. I already mentioned it, please read the reply.

Comment: There's no function called `strdup` in C, it is non-standard. So there's no reason to be smug about that one.

Comment: Like Lundin said, there is no `strdup` in `C`.  [If you need it, you need to write it yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224761/strdup-causing-memory-leaks/33224834#33224834)

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the complete error (not just the second). As a rule of thumb you should read errors from top to bottom as the subsequent errors may be a consequence of the former (or an explaination of the former). The second message just tells you that the memory allocated by `malloc` is not initialized, which is as expected - it's just an ammendmend to the first.

The fault lies in when you then use the allocated space without filling it with something useful. The fault lies in the newly posted code, the block pointed to by `cur->str` is probably uninitialized.

The fault is a bit tricky, since you use `strncpy`. It will only copy `strlen(text)` bytes an thereby skipping the null terminator. You've made space for it but it's not copied, consequently the last byte of the allocated buffer is not initialized (the error happens when `vfprintf` iterates through the string and reaches the byte where the null terminator should be).

To be clear about what `strncpy(dst, src, cnt)` does. It copies at most `cnt` bytes (including null terminator), if the `src` string including the null terminator is no longer than `cnt` bytes it will copy the full string. Otherwise it will only copy the first `cnt` bytes of the string and **not** null terminate `dst`.

Comment: cur->str is initialized in the newStr method

Comment: @Big_tboy I meant the data pointed to by `cur->str` is not fully initialized.

Comment: that why i am asking this question, clearly i have initialized this str in my newStr function

Comment: @Big_tboy You have allocated `strlen(text)+1` bytes, but only initialized the first `strlen(text)` bytes. The last byte, which should contain the null terminator is **not** initialized.